# Radical ideal in $k[X_{1},...,X_{n}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an field with $\mathrm{char}(k) = 0$ and $f_{1},...,f_{n} \in k[X_{1},...,X_{n}]$. Consider the jacobian matrix $A := (\frac{\partial f_{j}}{\partial X_{l}})$ and suppose that $\det(A) = 1$. Is it true that $\sqrt{(f_{1},...,f_{n})} = (f_{1},...,f_{n})$?

Note that if $n = 1$, then $\det(A) = 1 \Longrightarrow f_{1} = X+b$ with $b \in k$. So, $\sqrt{(f_{1})} = (f_{1})$.

Comment: Do you have any intuition for why this might be true, besides that it holds for $n=1$?

Comment: @Thomas: was trying to prove the following fact:
Let $f_{1}, ..., f_{n} \in k[X_{1}, ..., X_{n}]$ with $k = \overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}$. suppose that detA = 1. (as above).
Then the algebraic set determined by f1, ..., fn is finite.

I have an argument for this, but my initial idea would be to apply the Jacobian criterion to prove it. This led me to ask this question.

Comment: Maybe you should investigate the $n=2$ case.

Comment: @MooS: thanks for the argument.

Comment: As far as maximality is concerned. As you suggested, this seems to be equivalent to the Jacobian conjecture, hence there is very little hope that the two of us will either find a proof or a counterexample :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $R=k[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]/(f_1, \dotsc, f_n)$ and $X=\operatorname{Spec}R$. We have to show that $R$ is reduced.

We can assume that $k$ is algebraically closed, because the assumption on the Jacobian is certainly invariant after passing to the algebraic clousure and if $R$ were not reduced, $R \otimes_k \overline k$ were also not reduced by the virtue of the injection $R \hookrightarrow R \otimes_k \overline k$.

If $X=\emptyset$, we have nothing to show. Otherwise, let $x \in X$. By [this beautiful answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/79977/93853), we get $$\dim_{k(x)} \Omega_X \otimes k(x) = n-\operatorname{rank} J_x,$$

where $J_x$ is the Jacobian matrix evaluated at $x$. By your assumption on the Jacobian, we get $\dim_{k(x)} \Omega_X \otimes k(x)=0$, i.e. Nakayama yields $\Omega_{X,x}=0$. Since this holds for any $x \in X$, we get $\Omega_X=0$.

Next, let us show that $X$ is actually zero-dimensional. It suffices to show that any irreducible component of $X$ is zero-dimensional. By generic smoothness, any component admits a non-empty open $U$, where it is non-singular, i.e. $\mathcal \Omega_U$ is local free of rank $\dim U$. This shows $\dim U=0$ and since you check the dimension on any non-empty open subset in the finite type case, we have that any irreducible component is zero-dimensional, thus $X$ is zero-dimensional, i.e. a finite discrete set of points. This means $R = A_1 \times \dotsc \times A_s$ for local artinian rings $A_i$.

We are left to show that each $A_i$ is a field. Note that $A_i$ is a quotient of $R$, in particular it satisfies the assumption of Theorem II.8.8 in Hartshorne, thus $\Omega_{A_i}=0$ implies that $A_i$ is regular. A regular local artinian ring is a field.